# changing the table column names with information from the first row

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to change the column names of the table with the data from the first row using sql. I know I can do it manually but I am wondering if I can do it pragmatically. [image]

For example the table name COL 1 will change to Borough Block and Lot #

Comment: You'll have to script it out dynamically.

Comment: @xQbert That's not helpful.

Comment: @xQbert--that link doesnt really has the solution I am looking for

Comment: How many columns do you have? Unless it's a huge number I'd probably do this manually.  Do you really want to have columns with names like "Natural Gas (Con Edison or National Grid)"?  Also I see that you have some periods in your fields.  These are not going to be valid in column names.

Comment: @AllInOne--I have 30 columns. But what you are saying is a good point.

Answer (score 1):

SQL has no concept of "first row", because tables are inherently unordered.

You seem to have a problem on *importing* the data into the database.  It looks like the column names were imported as data values rather than as column names.

This can cause multiple problems.  For instance, `col8` appears to be a date.  However, the data type in the database is a character string.  It would be much more convenient for dates to be stored as dates, so `order by` and `>` (for instance) work on them.

I would suggest that you re-import your data and learn how to read the column names from the file.  Or, export the data and then re-import it into another table.

Comment: @Gordon-- I see what u=you are saying. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

For 30 columns I'd strongly recommend naming them manually.

I'd much prefer to have columns named like this:

```
facility_address
owner_name
owner_address
gas_provider
boiler_application_number
oil_phaseout_deadline
```

Instead of the garbage you'll get if you handle this programatically.

Also as I commented above, periods are not valid in column names so you'd have to handle those as an exception anyway.

Answer (score 1):

SELECT 'COL1' as COL1, 'COL2' as COL2, 'COL3' as COL3 FROM table

UNION

SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM table

But you need to know the names of the fields before with previous query

SHOW COLUMNS FROM table